# How to redirect a specific url to a different url on click in React?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, meta-tags

I was trying to implement a Facebook share button using dynamic meta tags in react, to share articles from my website. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time showing the image card of the article in the Facebook post - it only shares the URL. However, when I replace the URL meta tag with the URL of the image for example www.mywebsite/Images/myImage.jpg, Facebook shows the image as wanted. I was wondering if there is a way to still use the URL of the image, but redirect this URL to that of the article every time it's clicked.

If anyone knows the answer to this, I'd appreciate some help a lot!

This is how I'm declaring my URL for the url meta tag:

```
const currentURL = window.location.href;

const from = window.location.href.indexOf('image');
const fullurl = window.location.href.slice(from + 6);
```

...

```
<meta property="og:url"           content={fullurl}/>
<meta property="og:image"         content={fullurl}/>
```

...

```
 <FacebookShareButton className="mt-5 mb-3"  windowWidth="800"
                url={`${fullurl}`}
                >
       <FacebookIcon size={32} round={true} />
  </FacebookShareButton>
```

That is, I'm trying to find a way to redirect from fullurl to currenturl every time it's clicked, but still, use it for the meta tags.